# Can I track my workout and listen to music with Apple Watch Series 2 without having to carry my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, apple-watch, watchos

I do not have any experience with the Apple Watch, currently I am just using an iPhone. Before I buy an Apple Watch I would like to verify my question.

I know I need to pair it with an iPhone. But from what I have gathered, the new Apple Watch Series 2 is much more independent then the previous version.

1. Tracking should be possible with the GPS module.
2. [Pairing a bluetooth headphone](http://www.imore.com/how-pair-bluetooth-headset-your-apple-watch) is possible.
3. [Playing music](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204691) without iPhone is also possible.

Am I right? Or are there any limitations I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct on all three counts.

The Workout app will work without your iPhone, at least. Third-party apps might need to be updated to be completely independent. Strava, for instance, won't start without an active iPhone connection, but Runkeeper will.

Both the first generation WATCH and Series 2 support syncing of a single playlist up to either 2GB or 250 songs.

Comment: Apple watch has 5,7GB of storage , so you have more room for songs.